# Tick line not visible in linear time scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm playing around with D3 and want tick lines to cut through a linear time graph across the vertical axis. The tick line elements are there, with the correct vectors, but they do not appear. What appears instead is the path element that runs horizontally with the tick labels.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xdb2M/)

```
var width = 960;
var height = 200;
var container = d3.select(".timeTable");
var svg = container.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var roomID = container.attr("data-room");
var times = [
    {"from":"2012-12-27 00:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 12:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 00:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 23:59:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 02:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 04:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 03:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 21:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 03:30:00","until":"2012-12-27 04:50:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 05:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 12:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 09:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 15:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 13:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 23:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 13:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 23:30:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 20:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 23:59:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 20:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 22:00:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-27 23:00:00","until":"2012-12-27 23:30:00"},
    {"from":"2012-12-28 01:00:00","until":"2012-12-28 13:00:00"}
];
function draw(times) {
    // domain
    var floor = d3.time.day.floor(d3.min(times, function (d) { return new Date(d.from); }));
    var ceil = d3.time.day.ceil(d3.max(times, function (d) { return new Date(d.until); }));
    // define linear time scale
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([floor, ceil])
        .rangeRound([0, width]);
    // define x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(d3.time.hours, 6)
        .tickSize(4);
    // draw time bars
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(times)
        .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "timeRange")
            .attr("width", function (d, i) { return x(new Date(d.until)) - x(new Date(d.from)); })
            .attr("height", "10px")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(new Date(d.from)); })
            .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 11; });
    // draw x axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "xAxis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - 23) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
}
draw(times);
```

The path element generated simply overlaps the ticks, but the ticks are not visible even with path removed.

The desired tick effect is shown here [Population Pyramid](http://bl.ocks.org/4062085) - ticks on the vertical axis have a line that cuts through the rest of the graph.

Is there different behavior I need to be aware of for time scales?

Much appreciated.

Chrome 23, D3 v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to getting the tick lines into the plot area is to actually make a second axis and hide the labels. So your code plus the grid lines looks something like ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96XUd/)):

```
// draw x axis
var xAxisLine = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (height - 23) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

xAxisLine.selectAll("path.domain").attr("stroke","black").style('fill','none');
xAxisLine.selectAll("line.tick").style('stroke','black');

xAxis.tickSize(height-23);
var xAxisLineOver = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xAxis-overlay")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
    .call(xAxis);

xAxisLineOver.selectAll("path.domain").attr("stroke-width",0).style('fill','none');
xAxisLineOver.selectAll("line.tick").style('stroke','red');
xAxisLineOver.selectAll("text").text("");
```

Comment: Is this the intended behavior? It seems odd to me that it would put the tick elements in there and just not draw them, or maybe I am missing some detail about SVG. Thank you regardless.

Comment: with those code changes you should see two sets of tick elements. The main problem that gets me every time is that the domain path, for whatever reason, likes to default to a filled path which does not look right and covers the tick elements. There is actually a really good axes tutorial [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/) that I often go back to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the exact same problem I had. What worked for me was:

```css
.tick line{ 
  stroke: black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is very strict regarding rendering SVG. So keep this in mind:

1. For axes specify their full RGB value (so #ff0000 instead of just #f00).
2. Path stroke widths are tricky. If they are less than 1 (px) and you have included

   shape-rendering: crispEdges;

in CSS styles than any web browser might not display such path (or when the chart is resized to different size).

In that case comment or delete the "crispEdges" rendering and you should be fine (though in this case you leave the browser the smoothing decision).